# The unsubscribe page for "The Overflow" is broken

Tags: bug, subscriptions, the-overflow

I clicked the "Unsubscribe from emails like this" link at the bottom of this month's The Overflow email. It took me to an email settings page with a bunch of toggles. The toggle for The Overflow had been successfully switched to "Off", along with a confirmation message.

However, attempting to toggle any other option to "Off" does nothing. Upon checking my console, attempting to toggle any other setting returns a 403.

Comment: It's broken for 6 Month now???